# Convert JavaScript variable to MD5 hash using PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I want to convert my JS variable to its MD5 hash.
I think using passing JS variable to PHP and again use in JS i think this can be possible?
If no, is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: MD5 is not encryption. Encryption is a process which works 2 ways - what you encrypt, you can decrypt. MD5 is a hash function - it calculates the hash of the given input (a number represented in hexadecimal format). It's not reversible. Also, what you just said is pointless. Anyone with sufficient knowledge will take your code apart and see what's going on, whether you obfuscate it or not.

Comment: @N.B.: MD5 is not encryption. Encryption is a process which works 2 ways - what you encrypt, you can decrypt. > So MD5 will soon be an encryption ;)

Comment: ok sorry my fault i changed question

Comment: @PeeHaa - sure, if you consider collisions acceptable :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example for *PeeHaa* answer:

File **ajax.php**:

```
header( 'Content-type: text/javascript' );
$var = isset( $_GET['var'] ) ? $_GET['var'] : NULL;
echo md5( $var );
```

File **test.html**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_md5(str)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', '/ajax.php?var=' + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
function init_md5()
{
    var str = document.getElementById('str').value;
    get_md5(str);
}
</script>

str: <input type='text' id='str' value='test'/>
<input type='button' onclick='init_md5()' value='get md5'/><br/><br/>
md5: <span id='result'></span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an MD5 routine implemented in JS. I didn't write it. I also don't remember where I found it. Otherwise I would credit it.

**EDIT** Just found it again, I got it from [webtoolkit](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-md5.html).

```
var MD5 = function (string) {

  function RotateLeft(lValue, iShiftBits) {
    return (lValue<<iShiftBits) | (lValue>>>(32-iShiftBits));
  }

  function AddUnsigned(lX,lY) {
    var lX4,lY4,lX8,lY8,lResult;
    lX8 = (lX & 0x80000000);
    lY8 = (lY & 0x80000000);
    lX4 = (lX & 0x40000000);
    lY4 = (lY & 0x40000000);
    lResult = (lX & 0x3FFFFFFF)+(lY & 0x3FFFFFFF);
    if (lX4 & lY4) {
      return (lResult ^ 0x80000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
    }
    if (lX4 | lY4) {
      if (lResult & 0x40000000) {
        return (lResult ^ 0xC0000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
      } else {
        return (lResult ^ 0x40000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
      }
    } else {
      return (lResult ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
    }
  }

  function F(x,y,z) { return (x & y) | ((~x) & z); }
  function G(x,y,z) { return (x & z) | (y & (~z)); }
  function H(x,y,z) { return (x ^ y ^ z); }
  function I(x,y,z) { return (y ^ (x | (~z))); }

  function FF(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
    a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(F(b, c, d), x), ac));
    return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
  };

  function GG(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
    a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(G(b, c, d), x), ac));
    return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
  };

  function HH(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
    a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(H(b, c, d), x), ac));
    return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
  };

  function II(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
    a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(I(b, c, d), x), ac));
    return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
  };

  function ConvertToWordArray(string) {
    var lWordCount;
    var lMessageLength = string.length;
    var lNumberOfWords_temp1=lMessageLength + 8;
    var lNumberOfWords_temp2=(lNumberOfWords_temp1-(lNumberOfWords_temp1 % 64))/64;
    var lNumberOfWords = (lNumberOfWords_temp2+1)*16;
    var lWordArray=Array(lNumberOfWords-1);
    var lBytePosition = 0;
    var lByteCount = 0;
    while ( lByteCount < lMessageLength ) {
      lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
      lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
      lWordArray[lWordCount] = (lWordArray[lWordCount] | (string.charCodeAt(lByteCount)<<lBytePosition));
      lByteCount++;
    }
    lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
    lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
    lWordArray[lWordCount] = lWordArray[lWordCount] | (0x80<<lBytePosition);
    lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-2] = lMessageLength<<3;
    lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-1] = lMessageLength>>>29;
    return lWordArray;
  };

  function WordToHex(lValue) {
    var WordToHexValue="",WordToHexValue_temp="",lByte,lCount;
    for (lCount = 0;lCount<=3;lCount++) {
      lByte = (lValue>>>(lCount*8)) & 255;
      WordToHexValue_temp = "0" + lByte.toString(16);
      WordToHexValue = WordToHexValue + WordToHexValue_temp.substr(WordToHexValue_temp.length-2,2);
    }
    return WordToHexValue;
  };

  function Utf8Encode(string) {
    string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
    var utftext = "";
    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
      var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
      if (c < 128) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
      }
      else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      }
      else {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      }
    } 
    return utftext;
  };

  var x=Array();
  var k,AA,BB,CC,DD,a,b,c,d;
  var S11=7, S12=12, S13=17, S14=22;
  var S21=5, S22=9 , S23=14, S24=20;
  var S31=4, S32=11, S33=16, S34=23;
  var S41=6, S42=10, S43=15, S44=21;
  string = Utf8Encode(string);
  x = ConvertToWordArray(string);
  a = 0x67452301; b = 0xEFCDAB89; c = 0x98BADCFE; d = 0x10325476;
  for (k=0;k<x.length;k+=16) {
    AA=a; BB=b; CC=c; DD=d;
    a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S11,0xD76AA478);
    d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+1], S12,0xE8C7B756);
    c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S13,0x242070DB);
    b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+3], S14,0xC1BDCEEE);
    a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S11,0xF57C0FAF);
    d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+5], S12,0x4787C62A);
    c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S13,0xA8304613);
    b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+7], S14,0xFD469501);
    a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S11,0x698098D8);
    d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+9], S12,0x8B44F7AF);
    c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S13,0xFFFF5BB1);
    b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+11],S14,0x895CD7BE);
    a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S11,0x6B901122);
    d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+13],S12,0xFD987193);
    c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S13,0xA679438E);
    b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+15],S14,0x49B40821);
    a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S21,0xF61E2562);
    d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+6], S22,0xC040B340);
    c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S23,0x265E5A51);
    b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+0], S24,0xE9B6C7AA);
    a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S21,0xD62F105D);
    d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+10],S22,0x2441453);
    c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S23,0xD8A1E681);
    b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+4], S24,0xE7D3FBC8);
    a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S21,0x21E1CDE6);
    d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+14],S22,0xC33707D6);
    c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S23,0xF4D50D87);
    b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+8], S24,0x455A14ED);
    a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S21,0xA9E3E905);
    d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+2], S22,0xFCEFA3F8);
    c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S23,0x676F02D9);
    b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+12],S24,0x8D2A4C8A);
    a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S31,0xFFFA3942);
    d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+8], S32,0x8771F681);
    c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S33,0x6D9D6122);
    b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+14],S34,0xFDE5380C);
    a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S31,0xA4BEEA44);
    d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+4], S32,0x4BDECFA9);
    c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S33,0xF6BB4B60);
    b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+10],S34,0xBEBFBC70);
    a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S31,0x289B7EC6);
    d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+0], S32,0xEAA127FA);
    c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S33,0xD4EF3085);
    b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+6], S34,0x4881D05);
    a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S31,0xD9D4D039);
    d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+12],S32,0xE6DB99E5);
    c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S33,0x1FA27CF8);
    b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+2], S34,0xC4AC5665);
    a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S41,0xF4292244);
    d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+7], S42,0x432AFF97);
    c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S43,0xAB9423A7);
    b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+5], S44,0xFC93A039);
    a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S41,0x655B59C3);
    d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+3], S42,0x8F0CCC92);
    c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S43,0xFFEFF47D);
    b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+1], S44,0x85845DD1);
    a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S41,0x6FA87E4F);
    d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+15],S42,0xFE2CE6E0);
    c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S43,0xA3014314);
    b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+13],S44,0x4E0811A1);
    a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S41,0xF7537E82);
    d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+11],S42,0xBD3AF235);
    c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S43,0x2AD7D2BB);
    b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+9], S44,0xEB86D391);
    a=AddUnsigned(a,AA);
    b=AddUnsigned(b,BB);
    c=AddUnsigned(c,CC);
    d=AddUnsigned(d,DD);
  }
  var temp = WordToHex(a)+WordToHex(b)+WordToHex(c)+WordToHex(d);
  return temp.toLowerCase();
};
```

Comment: i know this, i don't want to use function sorry :(

Comment: @Ajay, huh? The create the MD5 hash of a string. What do you want?

Comment: i want to know is that possible to use JS variable in PHP, As i found it is not possible. What you think ?

Comment: The output of this routine is exaclty the same of the output of the PHP MD5 routine. So this js `MD5('hash me!');` == php `md5('hash me!');`. I often use this as a `String.prototype.md5 = function () ...`, all you need to do is change the line `string = Utf8Encode(string);` to `var string = Utf8Encode(this);` and change the way you declare it as above. Then you can call `hash = myStringVar.md5();` or indeed `hash = myMixedTypeVar.toString().md5();`.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the variable you want to hash using AJAX to a PHP file and let PHP return the hashed variable.

Comment: What's the point? Using the function from DaveRandom achieves the same result but without a network round trip.

Comment: i think PeeHaa solution will work and i know its not safe this is one experiment just

Answer (score 0):

Md5 is not decode-able. It is a one way street. Try using [base_64 encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) in php and [base64_decode](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) in js.